# Use a client certificate with git credential manager

Tags: git, windows-10, client-certificates, git-credential-winstore

We use a smart card at work for all authentication, including our git repos in TFS.

[git-credential-manager-for-windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) worked just fine with this using either SourceTree or the git command line directly on windows 7.

We've just upgraded to windows 10 and not the credential manager prompts me for a username/password, but no option for a certificate from my smart card, like I would expect.

I'm poring over the documentation, but can't find anything wrong. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I forgot to add that Visual Studio (through Team Explorer) is able to connect to the git repos just fine - I'm not sure how it authenticates...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a user error (helped along by a slight change in interface).

When connecting to our TFS it does prompt for username/password, but gives no options to choose a certificate. Apparently if I just hit OK and try without entering anything, if uses the correct client cert.

I'm not sure exactly how this is working, but I suspect it's something in the Windows Credential Manger.

So my problem is solved, but if anyone has any insight on *why* or *how* it works, I'm all ears.

Comment: Thanks that really helped me out. But this is really awkward. I've been trying for two days figuring it out and turns out this just a "bug"... when did it it just pushed my files.. lol